# How to find my current location in Mapkit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I was working on the Map kit where I want my current location to be displayed, but instead I am getting US location.

So can any one suggest me how to find the current location?

Comment: are you testing on device or simulator and it is common question you can find many answers posted on it

Answer (score 0):

On iOS5 Simulator by default you it will show some location in USA. If you want to change that location, in iOS Simulator menu, go to `Debug -> Location -> Custom Location`. There you can set the latitude and longitude and test the app accordingly. This works with mapkit and also with CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 0):

First import CoreLocation framework in your project.
Test this project in real device. You can not find current location of user in iOS Simulator.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];  
NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
```